# How to check Azure app has contributor role at subscription level?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azure-active-directory

I would like to check for an azure app , whether it has contributor role assigned to it at subscription level or not?

I think there would be a built way to check this.
Note : My app always been assigned contributor role at subscription level. So, this app is contributing at overall subscription. So, I need to consider subscriptionId for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As of now the web application is no longer assignes the **Contributor** role at the subscription level. At the subscription level, the web application will only have **Read** access.
- When you use the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) deployment type to create a cloud management gateway (CMG), the **Contributor** role assignment is limited to resource groups when the service is launched.
- If created through CMG then each subscription allows for up to 2000 role assignments. Role assignments at the subscription, resource group, and resource scope levels are all subject to this limit.
- The Role Assignments page contains a chart that counts the amount of role assignments for the current subscription to help you stay on track.

  [image: Access control - Number of role assignments chart]

**REFERENCES:**
[Contributor role is no longer assigned for a web app at the subscription level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/contributor-role-not-assigned-for-web-app)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the info.
But How about adding contributor role using REST by  Management API. I mean without using portal and doing programatically.? ( i.e. using HttpClient  with endpoint : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{Guid.NewGuid()}?api-version=2015-07-01

Comment: @Usman Yes, that would work too. For more information, please refer [Assign Azure roles using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest)